# how to create layered index in kibana dev tools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have created an index using kibana dev tools ,

```
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content_length": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "content_type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

once created in the indices tab, in the aws . it will look below

```
test
    count         373
    size in bytes 100 MIB
    Query total   200
    Mappings      _doc
                    content_length long
                    content_type keyword
```

but I have an example like this and not sure, how to structure my PUT request to get something like below.

```
test
    count         373
    size in bytes 100 MIB
    Query total   200
    Mappings      _doc
                    content_length long
                    content_type keyword
                    other
                       length text
                       data   text
```

the length and data properties are under "other" not directly under "_doc" above.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more by explaining it in detail ? The information you've provided is really confusing. Difficult to understand what kind of results you want to achieve.

Comment: @Harshit - I've edited my original question.